# remote access from ubuntu client to debian server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, remote-server

My PC : Ubuntu 16.05
The server : Debian 8.4 Jessie

So far I've been using ssh to connect to remote Linux servers and interfere with them through the console.

Can I connect to the server and see and interact with the graphical environment?
Like we do on remote desktop connection on Windows.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NX technology or VNC to access the server with graphical environment.

Remmina is the default linux application, which is used to connect the remote server/PC from client.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server has a graphical environment, then yes. You can install a VNC server on the server, and then use any VNC client to connect to it.